# Update label while user is typing in a TextField

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4.5

I'm trying to do a label be filled by a textfield while the user is typing in it:

.h

```
@interface MainView : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

And also .m:

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
    {
        label.text = textField.text;
    }
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textViewDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
    }
```

I've linked `label` with the label and `textField` with the textfield in storyboard.

But the app crashes when the ViewController is loaded:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILabel addTarget:action:forControlEvents:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7584ff0'

Any help here? : )

Comment: Sure looks like you linked the `textField` instance variable to a `UILabel`. Since that is what the error message says, I have to assume that is what happened unless somewhere in code you change what the `textField` property is pointing to.

Answer (score 3):

You are already implementing `UITextFieldDelegate` so you could just override `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` like:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
     // make sure it is the correct UITextField
     if ([textField isEqual:self.textField]) {
          // update UILabel
          self.label.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
     }
     return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a while for how to do this and it is pretty simple:

in the .h under you @interface Make a timer

```
 NSTimer *UpdateLabel;
```

Then in your .m do

```
-(void)UpdateLabel{
Label.text = Textfield.text;
Label.teaxtColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
UIFont *labelfont=[UIFont fontWithName:@"your Font" size:19];
[Label setFont:labelfont];
}
```

Then in your viewdidload do

```
UpdateLabel = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(UpdateLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```